# Passing map<>::iterator as map<>::const_iterator &

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator, const-iterator

I have a problem passing a map<...>::iterator object to a function as a const_iterator & on GCC:

```
class MyClass {


};

bool MyClass::_GetInstList(map<string,InstList>::const_iterator & it, const string & sMod)
{
    cout<<"Matched\n";
    it = tInstancesData.find(sMod);
    if( it == tInstancesData.end() ) {
        cout<<"\""<<sMod<<"\" is NOT a module\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

    bool SomeFunction()
    {

            map<string,InstList>::iterator  it;
            if( ! _GetInstList(it, SomeString) ) return false;
            it->second.Add(...);  //  Modifying element pointed by "it"

    }
```

My probelm is that on Visual Studio 2010 the code above works perfectly fine, but on GCC 4.1.2 I get an error saying there is no matching function to the function call, for _GetInstList(it, SomeString). The issue seems to be converting iterator to const_iterator &.

I have to take it by reference because "it" gets changed inside _GetInstList() and the caller function checks it. (The "it" pointer is changed not a pointed element).

Also, the "it" in SomeFunction() cannot be const because it changes an element.

How can I resolve this?

EDIT:
For those who suggest that the problem is the conversion from iterator to const_iterator:
The code compiles fine if the function prototype is changed to take const_iterator NOT as a reference, the problem is the const &.

Comment: Convert to const_iterator before calling? Or start with a const_iterator in the first place? Or make the code generic and accept any iterator.

Comment: Why does `_GetInstList()` need a `const_iterator`?

Comment: The standard says that `iterator` is *convertible* to `const_iterator`. It doesn't say that an `iterator` *is a* `const_iterator`, so the same does *not* apply for a reference to it. It doesn't inherit from it's const counterpart, so it is a conversion which needs a cast.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - I've done that and still got the same error. I need it as a NON-const iterator in the first place, as mentioned in the post.

Comment: I would change your `_GetInstList` to accept no iterator argument and simply return a pair of a `bool` (`true` if found) and a non-const iterator (valid if found). Wouldn't that make more sense?

Comment: @AndyProwl: +1. Or even return (and expose) the map's end(), making it even more idiomatic. (And, if you don't take Andy's suggestion, why not just make the argument a reference to an interator, rather than a const_iterator?)

Comment: @AndyProwl & rici - I can find an alternative and live with it (your suggestion to make it non-const iterator & is one option I thought about), I guess I wanted to know in general if it is possible to somehow take an iterator as a const_iterator &, which works on Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

Change your argument type to `const map<string,InstList>::const_iterator&` or just a `map<string,InstList>::const_iterator`.

Here's an example demonstrating your problem (and the solution) with simple types:

```
void func1(double& x){}
void func2(const double& x){}

int main()
{
    int x;
    func1(x); // error: 'func1' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'double &'
    func2(x); // succeeds
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I think maybe this method should be redesigned anyway. Passing iterators around is messy and confusing for others to read. How hard would it be to do that?

Comment: What do you suggest passing around instead of iterators?

Comment: The objects themselves? Either way, I think using iterators in function parameters does not provide a clean, reusable interface for others to use. Just my opinion.

Comment: The objects themselves cannot move over to the following objects.

Comment: The entire STL uses iterator pairs for functions (std::accumulate, std::copy, std::remove, etc.), so saying "passing iterators around is messy" is contradictory to the design choices of the STL.